# What's wrong with the API call request

Tags: api

Working on a third part API host. The API call requires a few key/value pairs in the request body with the following example fields:

```
field1: fieldValue1
field2: fieldValue2
field3: fieldValue3
field4: fieldValue4
```

The content type should be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
When using Postman to make the call, it's always successful. However, when changed to use a simple service to make the call, it's failing. The following is the piece of code that set up the HttpRequestMesage and make the call:

```
HttpResponseMessage response;

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())

{

     using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://soem.thirdpartyAPIHost.net"))
     {
           request.Content = new StringContent("{\"field1\":\"fieldValue1\",\"field2\":\"fieldValue2\",\"field3\":\"fieldValue3\",\"field4\":\"fieldValue4\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

     }
}
```

What's wrong with this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: the content type is Url encoded and therefore the string cannot be in Json format. Instead, the content key/value pairs should be chained together using '&', just like when the parameters are embedded in the Url. So, the sample content in the question should be like this:

request.Content = new StringContent("field1=fieldValue1&field2=fieldValue2&field3=fieldValue3&field4=fieldValue4", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Please also reference the following: How to send a POST request with Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"